# adding dispatch and context provider function as a useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, eslint, react-context

I have a react app where on some action a WS message is triggered. It hits the controller on the backend and does stuff then based on the outcome we send a happy or unhappy WS message back to our UI where we write the response in out Redux state (notifications) and that state is being listened on the child component being ready to display the notification box.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const setNotification = useNotification()

useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      setNotification(success, 'notice')
      dispatch(clearNotificationState())
    } else if (error) {
      setNotification(error, 'error')
      dispatch(clearNotificationState())
    } else if (warning) {
      setNotification(warning, 'warning')
      dispatch(clearNotificationState())
    } else return
  }, [error, success, warning])
```

What's confusing is that it asks to include the dispatch and the setNotification in dependency list.

This is my notification provider

```
const NotificationContext = React.createContext()


export function useNotification() {
  return useContext(NotificationContext)
}
```

Here is the ESLint warning I'm getting.

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'setNotification'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Can anyone explain why this is an issue? I am trying to remove the warnings, but not ready to do it at any cost, so if there is a better way to avoid it let me know. Or am I overthinking it and it is absolutely safe and correct to put these as useEffect dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation:

> It’s difficult to remember which props or state are used by functions outside of the effect. This is why usually you’ll want to declare functions needed by an effect inside of it. Then it’s easy to see what values from the component scope that effect depends on

That's why it expects your functions to be in the dependency array. Although that is not the case for all functions, I think omitting `dispatch` and `setNotification` from the array of dependencies would not cause any harm in your case.

For more information:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies